# How to return to the current debugging position in Chrome Dev Tools?

Tags: debugging, google-chrome-devtools

I keep finding a scenario where my code stops on a breakpoint in Chrome's debugger, then when I use another tab like "Console", and go back to "Sources", I have lost the place where the code stopped, and I have to click singles-step to get "back on track", but this skips past the sought after breakpoint. Is there some way to get to where the debugger has stopped?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the call stack portion to go to the current location the debugger is stopped at by clicking the top item in the call stack.

As the original writer couldn't submit an image due to his low reputation and the ongoing rules of the site, i will glady provide one for all of us!

[image]

Comment: No image, thanks, I haven't used this properly in a while, and overlooked the call stack,

Answer (score 2):

You can click on the breakpoint in the list of breakpoints in the breakpoint panel in Sources and it will take you back there.

Comment: Good question, possibly not

Answer (score 1):

You can see a line number below. (eg:Line    152, Column 1).
So give Ctrl+G+line number. eg:  Ctrl+G+152. You can see the breakpoint.