# How to return to current position in Chrome Dev Tools?

Tags: debugging, google-chrome-devtools

When I am debugging my code with Chrome Dev Tools I often jump around inside a file and between files, so that I leave the current position. Is there another way than going one step forward to return to the current position?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to go to the current breakpoint in Chrome console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30621661/how-to-go-to-the-current-breakpoint-in-chrome-console)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Call Stack (right panel) inside the Sources tab. The first entry is the current breakpoint.

You can also play around with breakpoints and reload the page.

Answer (score 0):

Already answered at the same (older and more answered question): https://stackoverflow.com/a/71621627/257561